# How to use xfire plugin in Spring Security based application developed with Grails Spring framework?

Tags: grails, xfire

I have developed a small application in Grails by using Spring Security plug in and it's working fine.

Now I want to make it a web service. By searching the web I found xfire plug in and installed it in my app and followed instructions as:

Made copied login controller code in login service and used `static expose=['xfire']`. When I run app getting wsdl code in browser, I am not understanding what to do next?

Comment: This old question seems to have been abandoned, and can probably be closed as 'unclear'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting wsdl code in your browser, then you're all set.  All the METHODS in the service class (not closures, methods) will be accessible as webservice methods.

For example, if your service was called "MyService", like:

```
class MyService {
   static expose=['xfire']

   public String reverse( String inp ) { return inp.reverse(); }
}
```

Now, someone can create a webservice client from your wsdl (http://yourhost/yourcontext/services/my?WSDL), and that client should be able to use the method "reverse", passing it a String, and getting the reversed String as the result.

If you'd like to know how to set up the web service client that USES your webservice.  Check out groovyWS or CXF.